# Page Layout and PickList for Custom Object

Tags: lightning, custom-object, picklist, page-layout

Let's say I have a custom object with 2 picklist fields. I've added this fields into page layout but i cannot see that ones. Wham am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Field Level Security on those picklist fields and make sure the fields are visible to the appropriate profiles.